# Android storing data online

Tags: android

I have ~5k active users own small app. I thought my app needs to that user favourites etc. saving data on online. And maybe add user login screen with Facebook or Google+ when saving data.

That's why I use Parse, Amazon? Which one is easy to use?

http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonSimpleDB/latest/DeveloperGuide/Welcome.html

https://parse.com/

I have own 5GB Bandwidth web server so what can I do? But I'm new in `PHP` language and maybe security problems? Or I should use JSon?

What would you suggest how I do?

Comment: parse is free .. things are simple there when its direct but when you go for relation database it goes complex .. and again when you go for parse its free upto certain limit !! Amazon is pay as you go and you are free to implements thinks your way and everything has to be done from scratch.

Comment: thankyou for comment.. yes, but more of things i want use my own server but maybe this will generate security problems :( ufff

Comment: use authentication and proper encryption of data .. use sessions and all with every request .. make it expire at proper time and if you are a bit confuse about own server implement things using parse Api instead of SDK and you are free to shift to your server any time just changing the links of the api without any change to logic

Comment: oww this so hard i dont know.. thank you for help

Answer (score 0):

The best known app use their own API.
So the best solution for you is to build a little API in you server.